# What's the best way to structure a log table which shows differently in each view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need to design the structure of a table that is going to store a log of events/actions for a project management website.

The problem is, these logs will be spelled differently depending on what the user is viewing

Example:

- On the overview, an action could say "John F. deleted the item #2881"
- On the single-item page, it would say "John F. deleted this item"
- If the current user IS John F. it would spell "You deleted this item"

I'm not sure if I should store each different possibility in the table, this doesn't sound like the optimal approach.

Comment: Wouldn't this be handled by code on the website? All the log table needs to store is which item and who deleted it.  When displaying the data you'd see if the user of the website was the same person who deleted it.

Comment: Thanks philyd, what about multiple "actions"? How should I store moving, updating, deleting, creating, renaming, modifying? Should there be an "action" field in the table with a code or something?

Comment: Yes, you can have a foreign key to an Actions lookup table.  This is likely the same way in which the user would be linked to the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate data from display.  In your log, store the complete information (user xxx deleted item 2881).  In your log viewer, you have the luxury of substituting as needed to make it more readable.

Answer (score 4):

For any kind of logs you can use the following table structure

CREATE TABLE `logs` (
`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`auto_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`table_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_by` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`updated_by_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3870 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

And then create another table to record what columns were updated exactly.

CREATE TABLE `logs_entries` (
`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`log_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`field_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`old_value` text,
`new_value` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `log_id` (`log_id`),
CONSTRAINT `logs_entries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`log_id`) REFERENCES `logs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7212 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3

Now your table data look like this

[image: Table structure and relations]

[image: Logs table data example]

[image: Logs child table where you records what data fields were changed]

Now Create a Database-View to fetch data easily in simple query

DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_logs_entries` AS
SELECT
`le`.`id`             AS `id`,
`le`.`log_id`         AS `log_id`,
`le`.`field_name`     AS `field_name`,
`le`.`old_value`      AS `old_value`,
`le`.`new_value`      AS `new_value`,
`l`.`auto_id`         AS `auto_id`,
`l`.`table_name`      AS `table_name`,
`l`.`updated_at`      AS `updated_at`,
`l`.`updated_by`      AS `updated_by`,
`l`.`updated_by_name` AS `updated_by_name`
FROM (`logs_entries` `le`
LEFT JOIN `logs` `l`
ON ((`le`.`log_id` = `l`.`id`)))$$

DELIMITER ;

After creating database-view your data will look like this, so now you can easily query any logs of your project

[image]

You must have noticed that I have added updated_by and updated_by_name columns in logs table, Now there are two ways to fill this updated_by_name column

1. You can write a query on every log entry to fetch user name and store it(not recommended)
2. You can make a database-trigger to fill this column (Recommended)

You can create database trigger like this, it will automatically insert user name whenever logs entry added in database.

DELIMITER $$

USE `YOUR_DATABASE_NAME`$$

CREATE
TRIGGER `logs_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `logs`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET new.updated_by_name= (SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE user_id = new.updated_by);
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

After doing all this, you can insert entries in logs table whenever you do changes in any database table. In my case I have PHP-CodeIgniter project, and I did it like this in my Model file, here I am updating patient table of my database

```
public function update($id,$data)
{
    // Log this activity
    $auto_id = $id;
    $table_name = 'patients';
    $updated_by = @$data['updated_by'];
    $new_record = $data;
    $old_record = $this->db->where('id',$auto_id)->get($table_name)->row();

    $data['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $return = $this->db->update($table_name,$data);
    //my_var_dump($this->db->last_query());

    if($updated_by)
    {
        $this->log_model->set_log($auto_id,$table_name,$updated_by,$new_record,$old_record);
    }

    return $return;
}
```

set_log function code checks which fields are actually changed

```
public function set_log($auto_id,$table_name,$updated_by,$new_record,$old_record)
{
    $entries = [];

    foreach ($new_record as $key => $value)
    {
        if($old_record->$key != $new_record[$key])
        {
            $entries[$key]['old_value'] = $old_record->$key;
            $entries[$key]['new_value'] = $new_record[$key];
        }
    }

    if(count($entries))
    {
        $data['auto_id'] = $auto_id;
        $data['table_name'] = $table_name;
        $data['updated_by'] = $updated_by;
        $this->insert($data,$entries);
    }
}
```

and insert log function look like this

```
public function insert($data,$entries)
{
    $data['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if($this->db->insert('logs', $data))
    {
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach ($entries as $key => $value)
        {
            $entry['log_id'] = $id;
            $entry['field_name'] = $key;
            $entry['old_value'] = $value['old_value'];
            $entry['new_value'] = $value['new_value'];

            $this->db->insert('logs_entries',$entry);
        }

        return $id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)  Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See the edit help re code block formats & table format. Please give table input as initialization code (in columns). [mre]